# When I start my discord bot I get an error on the console:

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js-player/src/lib/classes/queue/ytdl-core'
Require stack:
- D:\program\Discord bot\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\program\Discord bot\index.js:12:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\program\\Discord bot\\index.js' ]
}
```

The discord.js I installed. I looked around the internet but couldn’t find one that would solve the problem. I tried to reinstall Node.js but it won't come back. Please help! Thank You!

Comment: You should also post some relevant code; like what you try to import.

Answer (score 0):

### Requiring dependency of another package

From the error, I am assuming that you are attempting to require the `ytdl-core` package. However, you're currently trying to require it from the package `discord.js-player`. This will not work because `ytdl-core` is loaded separately from `discord.js-player` as a dependency. If you need the package separately, you should install it with `npm i ytdl-core` and require it with something like this:

```js
// index.js
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
```